# Cordova 3.5 iOS Compile Error

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, cordova-plugins

I just upgraded my phonegap project to cordova 3.5 and I can't compile my app anymore. Here is the output from Xcode:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVFile", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CDVCapture.o
     (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVFileTransfer, _OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVFileTransferEntityLengthRequest , _OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVFileTransferDelegate )
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVFilesystemURL", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CDVFileTransfer.o
  "_CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL", referenced from:
      -[ReaderThumbRender main] in ReaderThumbRender.o
  "_CGImageDestinationAddImage", referenced from:
      -[ReaderThumbRender main] in ReaderThumbRender.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CMMotionManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in iPhone_Sensors.o
      objc-class-ref in CDVAccelerometer.o
      objc-class-ref in libQCAR.a(libQCAR.a-armv7-master.o)
  "_CGImageDestinationFinalize", referenced from:
      -[ReaderThumbRender main] in ReaderThumbRender.o
  "_CGImageSourceCreateWithURL", referenced from:
      -[ReaderThumbFetch main] in ReaderThumbFetch.o
  "_CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex", referenced from:
      -[ReaderThumbFetch main] in ReaderThumbFetch.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I thought maybe that the linker flag for libCordova.a was off but that doesn't seem to be the problem. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: try this - make a copy of your www folder. create a new app with the updated cordova & replace its www with your folder & then try to compile it.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Had similar problem just now.

In your `Project > Targets` settings go to  `Build Phases > Compile Sources` and add all `*.m` files under `plugins` directory. This should solve the problem.

Comment: This is such a common problem, it should be a footnote on the Cordova Plugin registry website.